# ATI Radeon HD 5650 on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: drivers, ati, video

We've got a laptop running an ATI Radeon HD 5650 and we're trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 on it, yet without luck getting the drivers for the video card running correctly.

On the internet I've seen a lot of people speculating the Radeon HD 5650 needs the legacy drivers, instead of the default ones provided by AMD. Can anyone confirm this?

Any ideas on how to get this set up? We've already tried to install the proprietary drivers (without luck, X doesn't like them), as well as doing it through the downloadable drivers, available at AMD's website (both via the buildpkg and 'just run it' methods).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with a Radeon HD variant. There is no way around it while keeping your system at like-stock, don't even attempt. Go for any NVidia card or certified approved AMD Radeon card and you'll be good. NVidia has the best driver support out of any of the big two in graphics, Intel also has AMAZING support, but their graphics chips usually only on-motherboard or inside the CPU/APU.

Comment: Gotta love Intel, indeed! Thanks for your answer, I'll try to switch the ATI card off in the BIOS so it'll use the Intel graphics :-)

Comment: I guarantee this will work for you, compatibility-wise! :)